# How can I theme the Responsive Image module in a specific Paragraph Type

Tags: media, theming, paragraphs

I have a responsive image field inside two different paragraph types. I am on Drupal 8.3.7. I want to theme the module in one paragraph type but not the other.  I want to render a modified version of this code :

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21stable%21templates%21field%21responsive-image.html.twig/8.2.x

I tried putting my modified code inside responsive-image--field_my_resp_image.html.twig but it is not being used. I can't seem to find the correct filename for a theming a responsive image from a specific paragraph type. Any ideas?

My goal is to render embedded CSS for a background image instead of the HTML picture element that responsive images uses. Is there a better method than what I'm attempting above?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but I'm honestly not happy with it.  I can use 'responsive_image_style_id' to identify this responsive image. The problem with this approach is that it relies on specific keywords ('_style') in 'responsive_image_style_id' and if a site admin changes that, it will break :

```
function paia_theme_suggestions_responsive_image_alter(&$suggestions, $vars, $hook) {

  $newHook = str_replace('_style', '', $vars['responsive_image_style_id']);

  if ($newHook != $vars['responsive_image_style_id']) {
    $suggestions[] = $hook . '__' . $newHook;
  }
}
```

It seems I am using entirely the wrong approach for this, and I should probably be rolling my own module or something totally different. But I have a deadline to meet and I need to move on.